# MySQL UPDATE field where count on another field in the same table = 1

Tags: mysql, sql

Please could someone give me the correct syntax for below.

```
MySQL UPDATE tblcontact SET MainContact = 1 
WHERE COUNT(tblcontact.CompanyID) = 1 
GROUP BY tblcontact.CompanyID
```

Comment: you made zero effort to help us help you. Table structure, sample data, expected results...

Comment: Sorry I will include more information next time. I was trying to keep it as clear as possible using sudo code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the idea.  You want to set the field to 1 where there is only one record.  Try this:

```
UPDATE tblcontact c join
       (select CompanyID, count(CompanyID) as cnt
        from tblcontact
        group by CompanyId
       ) cc
       on c.CompanyId = cc.CompanyId and cnt = 1
    SET c.MainContact = 1 ;
```